# Write date using to_timestamp with full year and time

Tags: oracle11g

I need to run the following script but I got error:

> select distinct id
>   from    member
>   where  stop_date >= '01-JAN-2015 00:00:00'

When I do it this way, I don't get the error and the query run but I'm not sure this will get me the same result:

> select distinct id
>   from    member
>   where to_timestamp(stop_date, 'DD-MON-YY') >= '01-JAN-15'

How can I write using date written as : 01-JAN-2015 00:00:00 instead of 01-JAN-15?

Comment: You're not making it easy for us are you? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

`'01-JAN-2015 00:00:00'` is a **STRING** and NOT a **DATE**. Your column `stop_date` is DATE type. Now, when you are doing a comparison of a DATE column, it is obvious that you MUST use a DATE type and not STRING.

A date has both date and time elements. The **TIMESTAMP datatype** is an extension on the DATE datatype.

So, modify your query as:

```
select distinct id
    from    member
    where  stop_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

If you want the time portion to be set to **midnight 12**, i.e. `00:00:00`, then don't mention it at all.

Comment: If I use  select distinct id_number
    from    member
    where  ((to_date(stop_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') >= to_date('01-JAN-15','DD-MON-YYYY') I got an error. The error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: Where have I said to use TO_DATE on the stop_date column? Look at the answer once again. At least you should be able to copy paste the provided solution properly.

Comment: @MGL You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others as well.